# How to make alternating 'for' loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, negative-number

How do i make alternating step for a 'for' loop? i.e number sequence (-1,2,-3,4,-5)

I know how to make all negative which is

```
n=int(input())
for i in range (1,n+1):
    i=i*(-1)
    print(i)
```

im sure there's a better way to do it, but how do i make a 2nd step on for the n=2,4,6... ? putting another i=i*(-1) makes it all+ again

Answer (score 0):

I added if part that checks the number not even. It provides odd numbers to multiply with -1.

```
n=int(input())
for i in range (1,n+1):
  if i%2!=0:
    i=i*(-1)
  print(i)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce a parity check, i.e. check whether the value of `i` of the current interation is even or odd. This can be achieved using the modulo operator `%`.

```py
n = int(input())
for i in range(1, n+1):
  if i % 2 == 0:
    print(i)
  else:
    print(-i)
```

Comment: Isn't it exactly same as my answer?

Comment: Seems we have been posting the same answer at the same time.

Comment: @TDG: your answers were posted very close to each other, and they probably didn't see your answer. Additionally, there's really only one obvious way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use math
odd numbers are negative, -1 to power of a odd number is -1 so we multiply odd numbers by (-1)^i
same way for even numbers because -1 to power of even is +1 so generally in our case each number from <1, 2, 3, 4, ...> maps to <-1, 2, -3, 4, ...>

```py
>>> for i in range(1, n + 1):
...     j = i * (-1)**i
...     print(j)
... 
-1
2
-3
4
-5
```

Comment: Your answer would benefit from some explanation.

Comment: added explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Raising -1 to odd powers for -1 and even powers for +1 is how I'd do it. Depends on if you want "odd numbers negative" or "first third fifth numbers" negative.

You could also just maintain a "flip":

```py
flip = -1  # first number will be negative; make it 1 for first number postive
for i in range(1, n+1):
    print(i * flip)
    flip *= -1

# output:
-1
2
-3
4
-5
```

You can use [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) with list of `[-1, 1]` and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) it with your range.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think about this problem is that you have two sequences, one of positive values, one of negative ones and you alternate between them for producing the result. That is, you *interleave* values from those sequences. The third-party [Toolz](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library has lots of useful functions, like [`interleave`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.interleave):

```py
from toolz.itertoolz import interleave

n = 5
positives = range(2, n + 1, 2)
negatives = range(-1, -(n + 1), -2)

combined = interleave([negatives, positives])

for i in combined:
    print(i)
```